# Show size of shape in mm within the shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

In Photoshop, I would like to have text within a shape, which displays the dimensions of the shape in mm.

I would like it to automatically adjust itself when I change the size of the shape.

Is this even possible? I don't know much about macros, and google doesn't understand my question (it thinks i want the size of the text to equal the shape)...

Comment: Photoshop simply doesn't do any sort of dimensioning. I know there are web-building plugins out there though. i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dq01NqMuT0

Comment: i see the size of the shape in the info panel. I want those values written in the shape after i resize it

Comment: @Dave - there's no way to do this automatically with the standard functionality in Photoshop.  Not even sure if you could write a script for that, but that would require coding, and coding is generally off-topic here.